# How can I move a element in div like a chess board using input values like if input.value==1 ; moveUp(); and get currentPositon()

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm not able to create a 4/4 html table where I can put one element and move it using input values. Suppose, if input.value==1 then move up, input.value==2 then moveDown, input.value==5 then get current position

Comment: if you have tried any code then paste it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Want something like this? :

```
elementPos = {
  row: 2,
  column: 2
};

tableRows: number = 4;
tableColumns: number = 4;

ngOnInit() {
  this.refreshTable();
}

refreshTable() {
  tableHTML = '<table><tbody>';
  for(let i=0;i<this.tableRows;i++) {
    tableHTML += '<tr>';
    for(let j=0;j<this.tableColumns;j++) {
      if (this.elementPos.row === i && this.elementPos.column === j) {
        tableHTML += '<td><div>My Element</div></td>';
      } else {
        tableHTML += '<td></td>';
      }
    }
    tableHTML += '</tr>';
  }

  document.querySelector('#myTableDiv').innerHTML = tableHTML;
}

updateElePosOnInput(val) {
  switch(val) {
    case 1:
      this.elementPos.row -= 1;
      break;
    case 2:
      this.elementPos.row += 1;
      break;
    default:
      this.elementPos.row = 2;
      this.elementPos.column = 2;
  };
  this.refreshTable();
}
```